# In IOS app, feed often shows error

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

Whenever I try to see the feed , it shows me this error

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of a description of this 'error'?

Comment: Ya sure.in the IOS app UI they have given an option "FEED" below the user profile. Whenever I try to open it ,it shows me request time out . Have updated my question

Comment: Do you by any chance use both the beta app and public app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No